# Routing to different WebAPI controller's action where optional route param exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have my MVC 4 Project API Routing configured as follow:

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var company = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbCompany"];
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "MyApp/"+ company +"/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "main" , id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
       config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

 }
```

and MainController.cs contains the following methods:

```
    public JToken Get(string id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public JToken Get()
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JToken DoQuery([FromBody] String query)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Post([FromBody] JObject JsonObject)
    {
       ...
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is for any route that is not :

```
     route: /MyApp/MyComp/DoQuery
     method: POST 
     ContextType: text/plain 
     Returns: JToken
```

To use normal Get/Post of the main controller 
Otherwise use DoQuery in the main controller.

Comment: Please check if my edit matches your problem - based on code it looks WebAPI, but you text seemed to refer to MVC controllers/routing.

Comment: Yes it is, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you are missing is the special case route to map to `DoQuery`.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var company = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbCompany"];

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DoQuery",
            routeTemplate: "MyApp/"+ company +"/DoQuery",
            defaults: new { controller = "main", action = "DoQuery" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "MyApp/"+ company +"/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "main" , id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

}
```

Comment: When doing this im getting the following error when trying to POST to MyApp/MyComp a Json Data: Multiple actions were found that match the request:  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken DoQuery(System.String) on type MyApp.Controllers.MainController\r\nVoid Post(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) on type MyApp.Controllers.MainController